# How to setup rebus to handle messages from third party vendor

Tags: rebus

We currently use Rebus and we have a shared project that holds the command messages (payloads, etc).

Both the client and the bus projects reference this shared "messages" project. When the client sends a message to the bus, the bus knows how to handle it because it has references to the same namespace:

To illustrate, we have 3 projects:

- project.rebus.bus
- project.rebus.messages (command messages)
- project.rebus.client

Solution1 - bus

- project.rebus.bus
  `PingHandler<Ping>`
- project.rebus.messages (Ping message)

Solution2 - client

- project.rebus.client
  `bus.send(new Ping {...})`
- project.rebus.messages (Ping message)

The scenario works because both **project.rebus.bus** and **project.rebus.client** share the same **project.rebus.messages**, all good.

How do we setup **project.rebus.bus**, when it needs to handle messages from a third party vendor, where we can't have a shared **project.rebus.messages** project?

Is it possible?

***Example:***

Our rebus bus - bus

- project.rebus.bus
  `ThirdPartyTestHandler<ThirdPartyTestMessage>`
- project.rebus.messages (ThirdPartyTestMessage message)

Third party vendor - client

- SomeCompanyOutThere.rebus.client
  `bus.send(new ThirdPartyTestMessage {...})`
- SomeCompanyOutThere.rebus.messages (ThirdPartyTestMessage message)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty common to see projects where the messages assemblies are distributed as NuGet packages.

This way, the "owner" of the message types (i.e. the app with the handlers if it's commands, we're talking about, or the app that publishes the events if it's events we're talking about) can have the project in its solution, and then a NuGet package can be built from it.

All other apps (which then become "clients" in this particular relationship) can then include that NuGet package and this way get access to the message types.

I suggest you do the same with the 3rd party assembly, if you intend to use that as messages.

Comment: Thanks Mogens! I guess I should have thought about that. So, just to be clear, there is no way for Rebus to deserialize an incoming command message from a namespace it does not know, correct? I only ask because another team here uses NServiceBus, and apparently there is a config item in NServiceBus for this purpose.  Eventually, they will be replacing their NServiceBus bus with Rebus... Thanks again!

Comment: Oh it's definitely possible – but the builtin serializer will include the full .NET type name (in the form of the "simple assembly-qualified name", e.g. like `System.String, mscorlib`) as a header, which means that the recipient must be able to look up a type by that exact name when it receives the message. But that's the builtin serializer – you can also pass some `JsonSerializerSettings` to the serializer, and customize lots of things that way, or – in the extreme case – you can simply use your own `ISerializer` implementation

Comment: This is now possible with `UseCustomMessageTypeNames`, see [Customize Message routing key](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/863#issuecomment-595186174) for further info.